# .Net 5: Hosting ASP.NET Core gRPC Service in IIS 10 at Windows Server 2019

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc, iis-10, .net-5, grpc-dotnet

According to this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) in Microsoft Doc and this warning section:

> ASP.NET Core gRPC has extra requirements for being used with Azure App
> Service or IIS. For more information on where gRPC can be used, see
> gRPC on .NET supported platforms.

I created an `ASP.Net Core gRPC` service in `.NET 5` with `Grpc.AspNetCore(2.34.0)` package using above document guidline.

I hosted my service in IIS as for this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

**My problem**: I get an error in the call `RPC` method from the Client.

Given Error:

```
Status(StatusCode="Cancelled", Detail="No grpc-status found on response.")
```

**Additional**: I have searched on the web and investigate many issues, But these issues not help me. still, I have this error. I guess have a miss understanding or missed issue about this action.

***My primary question***: Actually is possible to Hosting ASP.NET Core Grpc Service in IIS at this time.

`OS`: Windows Server 2019 Version 1809 Build 17763.1697

`IIS`: Version 10.0.17763.1

Client Code:

```
    using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://192.168.13.155");
    var client = new ProccessMessage.ProccessMessageClient(channel);
    try
    {
        var result = client.GetMessage(new Request { Name = "Message" });
    }
    catch (RpcException ex)
    {
        string message = ex.Message;
    }
```

I get this exception: `Status(StatusCode="Cancelled", Detail="No grpc-status found on response.")` in catch block.

Comment: What you posted isn't an exception or error message. How was this generated? If the status is `Cancelled`, has the *client* cancelled the request due to a timeout perhaps?

Comment: Right now, it's impossible to guess what's wrong as there's no client or source code, no error messages, no environment information apart from `ASP.NET Core on Windows Server 2019`. The document you linked to explains that you need Windows Server Build 20241 to deploy to IIS, which was released on [October 2020](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-insiders/announcing-windows-server-preview-build-20241/m-p/1804897)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edited my question. my client has the basic configurations and no ane extra confoguration

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have added OS and IIS versions to the question.

Comment: The document you linked to explains you need a newer build

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That means updating the Windows server version solves the problem?

Comment: gRPC utilizes newer HTTP2 features like bidirectional streaming - IIS does not support them mainly because HTTP protocol driver in Windows HTTP.sys does not support those advanced features.

Comment: "gRPC on .NET supported platforms" - mentions about the upgraded HTTP.sys driver that took place on Windows 10 Build 19529 - is required. Is it also upgraded on Windows Server 2019 some build no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Windows Server 2019** - for hosting gRPC with IIS using (in-process) .NET 5 is not yet supported!

Reference:
[Host grpc service in iis or as an app service](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9020)

Comment: `ASP.NET Core gRPC Services` Can be hosted in `IIS` from `Windows Server Build 20241` and later.

Comment: I upgraded My Server `OS` version to this build and my problem is solved.

Comment: Windows 10 / Windows Server Insider builds are only supported yet, we still await if they will backport these Windows V.Next features to Windows Server 2019 or not, if yes, not sure when. Therefore this feature with Windows and IIS is so far experimental or beta.

One can try alternate gRPC Web or ASPNetCore's HTTPSysServer..
For me I do not consider them solutions..

Comment: It's not a .NET 5 problem - it's HTTP.sys in Windows.  Windows 2022 or a preview/insider build should support these trailing headers.